# cURL 5 - Proxy not resolved

Tags: linux, curl, http-proxy

I am trying to execute the following:

`curl twitter.com`

But I have got the proxy `http://proxyurl:port` set in `~/.curlrc`

However, when executing `curl twitter.com` I am getting

```
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: proxyurl
```

I have tried almost everything such as defining http_proxy in `~/.bashrc`

But still no luck.

So two questions, what does it mean by could not resolve proxy,

and secondly how do I resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819524/curl-through-proxy-syntax

Comment: @AvalSarri thanks for your reply, the steps in that thread does not help me, but I do have a question, the proxy I made is meant to be a local proxy, meaning the dns wasnt assigned to an ip address, so will I need to add that ip in the hosts file and assign it an IP addy

Comment: I am not able to understand this, for proxy can you use IP and check instead using a hostname? ping to proxy-ip works?

Answer (score 0):

it means:
you didn't totally remove your proxy, in other words to be able to resolve it after commenting your settings or delete the config of your proxy in the ~/.bashrc file, you need to unset the proxy variables by using the following command
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset https_proxy
to double check if the proxy is totally removed just execute this command:
env | grep -i proxy
after that your problem is resolved
hope this will help you